# View incoming WebRTC connection

Tags: webrtc

With all these p2p video applications, I am curious how one could view (in an external player such as vlc) the WebRTC data streams? I started using netstat to see incoming connections, but that didn't get me anywhere. I was hoping that there is a way to view webRTC data streams outside of the browser.

For example, in firebug it's easy to view POST and GET requests, however there's nothing on WebRTC connections.

Comment: It's not possible. You can use wireshark to see what kind of data webRtc sends, however you can't play it in VLC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to actually play the media, there is not a way. It is encrypted with a key that is exchanged in the DTLS handshake at the beginning of the peerconnection.

You can see the UDP packets in wireshark(their source and destination ports) but the media type and actually being able to play it is not possible unless you are privy to the master key exchanged so that you can decrypt the media(which is not possible if you are using the browser javascript APIs).